# ListView: Change color on certain parts of SubItem Text?

Tags: c#, listview

How could i for example make the first three characters of a ListView subitem text a different color than the rest? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible using [ListViewItem.SubItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.aspx). It only allows you to set a ForeColor for the entire item.